# Matching digits, x,xxx,xxx but not xx,xx,x, using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm building a regex that finds numbers in standard number format. Three digit, comma, three digits, comma, etc...

So it must match `1,234`, `23,322`, `1,234,567` and `12` but not `1,23,1`, `,,1111`, or anything else silly.

I have the following.

```
import re

testStr = '1,234,343'
matches = []
numComma = re.compile(r'^(\d{1,3})*(,\d{3})*$')

for group in numComma.findall(str(testStr)):
    Num = group
    print(str(Num) + '-')           #Printing here to test each loop
    matches.append(str(Num[0]))
```

Which outputs this:

```
('1', ',343')-
```

I'm not sure why the middle `,234` is being skipped over. Can anyone help me?

---

So after following all your advice, I tried the following code which works for some input.

```
testStr = '1,234,343'
numComma = re.compile(r'^(?:\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*$')

Num = numComma.findall(testStr)
print(Num)                      # ['1,234,343']
```

but not for others:

```
testStr = '1,234,343 and 12,345'
numComma.findall(testStr)       # []
```

So the purpose of the exercise is to be able to eventually scan a block of text and pick out all the numbers in this format. Any insight? I thought this would add an additional tuple, not return an empty one...

---

I examined all the help I've received and here's what I've come up with, and it appears to work.

My final code:

```
testStr = '12,454 So hopefully will match 1,234 and 23,322 and 1,234,567 and 12 but not 1,23,1 or ,,1111, or anything else silly.'

numComma = re.compile(r'''
    (?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))  # Looks behind the Match for start of line and whitespace
    ((?:\d{1,3})        # Matches on groups of 1-3 numbers.
    (?:,\d{3})*)        # Matches on groups of 3 numbers preceded by a comma
    (?=\s|$)''', re.VERBOSE)    # Looks ahead of match for end of line and whitespace

Num = numComma.findall(testStr)
print(Num)
```

Which returns:

```
['12,454', '1,234', '23,322', '1,234,567', '12']
```

Comment: Why are you using findall?

Comment: It's not the problem, but your regexp is wrong. The first `*` is a mistake and allows the pattern to match things not in standard form: `'1234'` and `',123'` for example.

Comment: I'm using findall because I'm a complete and total newcomer fumbling his way around :) I will read up on the different methods and follow the advice flowing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact you're using a repeated capturing group, `(,\d{3})*` in your pattern. Python's regex engine will match that against both the thousands and ones groups of your number, but only the last repetition will be captured.

I suspect you want to use non-capturing groups instead. Add `?:` to the start of each set of parentheses (I'd also recommend, on general principle, to use a raw string, though you don't have escaping issues in your current pattern):

```
numComma = re.compile(r'^(?:\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*$')
```

Since there are no groups being captured, `re.findall` will return the whole matched text, which I think is what you wanted. You can also use `re.find` or `re.search` and call the `group()` method on the returned `match` object to get the whole matched text.

Comment: It's a good explanation, but the suggested regex matches number strings `'1234'`, `',123'`, `'1234,123'` and many other variations

Comment: @mhawke: yep, just noticed that. The `*` for the first group is also wrong, though that's not what was causing the specific issue the question was about, so I didn't notice it. I've fixed the pattern in my answer now.

Comment: The revised regex works perfectly now. A very minor and pedantic point is that it will not accept negative numbers... easily fixed by adding `-?` just after the caret at the start.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

A regex match will return a tuple item for each group. *However*, it is important to distinguish a *group* from a *capture*. Since you only have two parenthese-delimited groups, the matches will always be tuples of two: the first group, and the second. But the second group matches twice.

`1`: first group, captured
`,234`: second group, captured
`,343`: *also* second group, which means it *overwrites* `,234`.

*Unfortunately*, it seems that vanilla Python does not have a way to access any captures of a group other than the last one in a manner similar to .NET's regex implementation. *However*, if you are only interested in getting the specific number, your best bet would be to use `re.search(number)`. If it returns a non-`None` value, then the input string is a valid number. Otherwise, it is not.

Additionally: [A test](https://regex101.com/r/km8ppL/1) on your regex. Note that, as Paul Hankin stated, test cases 6 and 7 match even though they shouldn't, due to the first * following the first capturing group, which will make the initial group match any number of times. Otherwise, your regex is correct. [Fixed version.](https://regex101.com/r/5BCfMo/1)

RESPONSE TO EDIT:
The reason now that your regex returns an empty set on ' and ' is because of the ^ and $ anchors in your regex. The ^ anchor, at the start of the regex, says 'this point needs to be at the start of a string'. The $ is its counterpart, saying 'This needs to be at the end of the string'. This is good if you want your entire string from start to end to match the pattern, but if you want to pick out multiple numbers, you should do away with them.

*HOWEVER!*
If you leave the regex in its current form sans anchors, it will now match the individual elements of 1,23,45 as separate numbers. So for this we need to add a *zero-width positive lookahead assertion* and say, 'make sure that after this number is either whitespace or the end of a line'. You can see the change [here](https://regex101.com/r/OPZNgU/1). The tail end, `(?=\s|$)`, is our lookahead assertion: it doesn't capture anything, but just makes sure criteria or met, in this case whitespace (`\s`) or (`|`) the end of a line (`$`).

BUT: In a similar vein, the previous regex would have matched 2 onward in "1234,567", giving us the number "234,567", which would be bad. So we use a look*behind* assertion similar to our lookahead at the end: `(?<!^|\s)`, only match if at the beginning of the string or there is whitespace before the number. This version can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/gPpvIA/1), and should soundly satisfy any non-decimal number related needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))((?:\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*)(?=\s|$)', re.DOTALL)

test_str = """1,234 and 23,322 and 1,234,567 1,234,567,891 200 and 12 but
not 1,23,1 or ,,1111, or anything else silly"""

for m in re.findall(p, test_str):
    print m
```

and it's output will be

- 1,234
- 23,322
- 1,234,567
- 1,234,567,891
- 200
- 12

You can see demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fH3cT1/3)

Answer (score 0):

This regex, would match any valid number, and would never match an invalid number:

> `(?<=^|\s)(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})*))(?=\s|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/dA4yB1/1